# Clean url with /blogo/testing-view_5.html and all php file will be .html .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I need some help

`/blogo/testing-view_5.html` this what i need

This will refer to `blogview.php?id=5`.

`testing-view` is only for show - no meaning

Comment: please give us some more info

Comment: Did you try anything from your side? Please share your code example to us

Comment: Welcome. Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).